# Bankers algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, resources, deadlock, bankers-algorithm

I have a question about the answer to a problem on Dijkstra's Banker's Algorithm (the question is provided in the screen shot below).

I thought the answer to this question should be "yes, it is possible to do it". My thinking is that once user 1 is done, we can pop him out and free his requested resouces (10 A's and 5 B's), and return his used resources to the available resources pool, which will assist the others to be done.

Instead, the answer (in the screen shot beneath the question) states it's not possible. Where did I go wrong? Why is the answer that this is not possible?

[image]

Answer:
[image]

Comment: I would have preferred if you'd re-written the question in your own words. Also, please don't tag with irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with Java or C.

Comment: What you want from us? To view your screen shot...????

Comment: what's your problem (besides your homework)?

Comment: @AchintyaJha I want to understand why the answer is what it is. I can't comprehend it.

Comment: @Aboutblank I do not understand the answer

Comment: In Bankers algorithm first the resource is given to the process which needs it then it checks that it can lead to deadlock or not. if yes then resource is allocated to other process and so on...Am I right?

Comment: @AchintyaJha you have no clue what you are talking about

Comment: I fail to see how this is "not a real question". It's obvious what the question is, Richard said he assumed the answer was "yes" because of this logic, but the book answer was "no" and he doesn't get it... That seems like a real question to me.

Comment: @Mike unfortunately StackOverflow is infested with trolls hunting for brownie points.

Comment: @Richard - I'm afraid sometimes when people don't see a `?` in a question, they assume it should be closed as not a real question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a poorly worded question. The problem description states that the available resources are `A = 10` and `B = 15`.

In the Banker's algorithm it's considered "safe" if a process can allocate the maximum resources it needs. (process 1 needs 10 A's and 5 B's)

Then the answer states the available resources are `A = 1` and `B = 2`. If you look at all the processes currently allocated numbers:
process 1 has 2 A resources
process 2 has 3 A resources
process 3 has 2 A resources
process 4 has 2 A resources
---------------------------
total A resources in use = 9

it becomes clear that the question meant those were the Total System resources, not current available resources. Thus 9 A resouces are in use, process 1 requires a maximum of 10 (it has 2) so it needs 8 more; in which case the answer is no, it's not safe.